# Different execution plans for Toad and Jasper Report?

Tags: sql, oracle, jasper-reports

I have encountered a strange situation in which an SQL query takes several seconds to complete when run from Toad and a Jasper Report containing the same query takes over half an hour to produce results (with the same parameters). Here are some details:

- I checked, and Oracle (version 11g) uses different execution plans in these two cases.
- I considered using stored outlines, but the report slightly modifies the query (bind variables are renamed; in the case of multiple values, i.e. $P!{...}, the report simply inserts values into the query, and there are too many combinations of values to bypass this), so outlines won't work.
- I ran the report in iReport 5.1 and via OpenReports and it takes about 35 minutes for both.
- The original query is tuned with some hints, without them it takes comparably long to complete as the report.

I would appreciate any advice on how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use TOAD for query tuning. It is in TOAD's interest to present you the first few rows of the result set as fast as possible, to make the application as responsive as possible. To do so, TOAD injects a FIRST_ROWS hint to your query. A nice feature, but not for tuning queries.

Now, to address your query that's taking too long, I suggest you first investigate where time is being spent. You can do so by tracing a query execution, as explained [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/1814597). Once you have done that, and you know where time is being spent, but you still don't know how to solve it, then please post the execution plan and statistics.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably differences in the optimizer environment. You can check this using

```
select * from 
V$SES_OPTIMIZER_ENV
where sid = sys_context(’userenv’,’sid’)
```

Run this in your toad session and in a Jasper report and compare the results.